# How many subgraphs of $(K_n)^-$ are isomorphic to $(K_5)^-$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

my question says

> How many subgraphs of $(K_n)^-$ are isomorphic to $(K_5)^-$? Let $(K_n)^-$ be a graph obtained from $K_n$ by deleting any one of its edges.

I thought about using Cayley’s Formula but do not know whether to apply it here.

I am having a hard time visualizing and understanding the logic behind this question, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints.

To visualize this question, color one edge in the graph $K_n$ red.
Let the red edge connect vertices $u$ and $v$.
Now your question can be phrased like this.

> 1. How many ways to choose five vertices out of $n$ such that
>    no two of them are connected by a red edge?
>    Each such five vertices makes it possible to form 10 graphs isomorphic to $K_5^-$.

> 2. How many ways to choose five vertices out of $n$ such that among them
>    there are vertices $u$ and $v$?
>    That is, in fact we have to choose three vertices from $n-2$ vertices.

The final result is
$$
10\left( {n\choose5}-{n-2\choose3}\right)+{n-2\choose3}.
$$

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use vertices $u$ or $v$ to get a subgraph isomorphic to $(K_5)^-$. (Unless all the subgraphs are secretly induced subgraphs, which is not stated.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov thank you. Corrected my answer. I hope it is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be the vertex set of $K_n^-$. How many size-$5$ subsets of $V$ induce an isomorphic copy of $K_5$, and how many induce an isomorphic copy of $K_5^-$? Can you finish? (All subgraphs isomorphic to $K_5^-$ are either among these $K_5^-$s or are subgraphs of these $K_5$s. Does that make sense?)